# Return an array containing hex-codes from a list of colors, based on an indexed type string array

Tags: javascript

I have two types of arrays:

`colorList` Contains a predefined set of colours:

```
var colorList = [
  '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
  '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];
```

And `dataFromSql` contains certain with classes, which corresponds to index of `colorList` :

```
 var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'];
```

`finalColor` will be a list of array from `colorList`. Their secquence will be as defined in `dataFromSql`

**Output:**

```
var finalColor = ['#ff7f50','#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#da70d6','#da70d6','#32cd32'];
```

Comment: im not sure how the 2 arrays relate.

Comment: looks like dataFromSql values are character based indexes of the values in colorList

Comment: Have you tried coding anything at all? You need to iterate over `dataFromSql`, check if the value is a new one. If so, take one colour from the colour array and asign it (e.g. using a string-indexed array) to that value. It not, just take the colour in your string-indexed array.

Comment: @BenSewards Maybe they meant A, B, … to be generic examples, i.e. B is any string different from string A.

Comment: Yes, it is just a dummy example. A,B,C,D,... are different strings. I would like to attach to each string a different color to use in a bar chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var colorList = [
  '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
  '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];
var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'];
var colors = {};
var finalColor = [];
dataFromSql.forEach(function(value){
    if (!colors[value]) {
        colors[value] = colorList.shift();
    }
    finalColor.push(colors[value]);
});
console.log(finalColor);
```

**Edit:** if you'll have more unique values in `dataFromSql` than colors in `colorList` I would recommend you to use following code snippet:

```
var colorList = [
  '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
  '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];
var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K' ,'L'];
var colors = {};
var finalColor = [];
var uniqueCount = 0;
dataFromSql.forEach(function(value){
    if (!colors[value]) {
        colors[value] = ++uniqueCount;
    }
    finalColor.push(colorList[colors[value] % colorList.length]);
});
console.log(finalColor);
```

Comment: @Aurel300 I'm not so fast to copy your code and change it for 1 minute. But yes, we have very similar implemetations because it's very easy task.

Comment: and what happens if we add another 'A' at the end of dataFromSql

Comment: @BenSewards We mostly assumed that the colour for A should be the same, even if they are not consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

```
var colorList = [
    '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
    '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];
var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'];
var finalColor = [];
var assignedColors = [];
for (var i = 0, l = dataFromSql.length; i < l; ++i){
    if (!assignedColors[dataFromSql[i]]){
        assignedColors[dataFromSql[i]] = colorList.splice(0, 1)[0];
    }
    finalColor.push(assignedColors[dataFromSql[i]]);
}
```

Just the general idea, add lots of error checks, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate a color to each class, you can do something like this:

```js
var colorList = ['#ff7f50', '#87cefa', '#da70d6', '#32cd32', '#6495ed', '#ff69b4', '#ba55d3', '#cd5c5c', '#ffa500', '#40e0d0'];
var dataFromSql = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D'];

var classCollors = {};
var index = 0;
var currentClass = 'A';
dataFromSql.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i == currentClass) {
    classCollors[i] = colorList[index];
  } else {
    index++;
    currentClass = i;
    classCollors[i] = colorList[index];
  }

});

console.log(classCollors);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary object for the colors.

> ```
> {
>     "A": "#ff7f50",
>     "B": "#87cefa",
>     "C": "#da70d6",
>     "D": "#32cd32",
>     "E": "#6495ed",
>     "F": "#ff69b4",
>     "G": "#ba55d3",
>     "H": "#cd5c5c",
>     "I": "#ffa500",
>     "J": "#40e0d0"
> }
> ```

```js
var colorList = ['#ff7f50', '#87cefa', '#da70d6', '#32cd32', '#6495ed', '#ff69b4', '#ba55d3', '#cd5c5c', '#ffa500', '#40e0d0'],
    dataFromSql = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    colorObject = {},
    finalColor;

colorList.forEach(function (a, i) {
    colorObject[(i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase()] = a;
});

finalColor = dataFromSql.map(function (a) {
    return colorObject[a];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(finalColor, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```
var colorList = [
  '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
  '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];

var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'];

var finalColor = [];

var tempArray = [];

dataFromSql.forEach(function(i) {
     console.log(i);
     if (tempArray.indexOf(i) === -1) {
       tempArray.push(i);
     }
     finalColor.push(colorList[tempArray.indexOf(i)]);
});


console.log(finalColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Understandable & Clear Answer.

```
var colorList = [
  '#ff7f50','#87cefa','#da70d6','#32cd32','#6495ed',
  '#ff69b4','#ba55d3','#cd5c5c','#ffa500','#40e0d0'
];

function getColors(items){
    var colors = [];
    items.forEach(function(c) {
        c = c.toUpperCase();
        var index = c.charCodeAt() - 65; // 65 for 'A';
        colors.push(colorList[index]);
    });

    return colors
}

var dataFromSql = ['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'];


var finalData = getColors(dataFromSql);
// Outputs : ["#ff7f50", "#ff7f50", "#87cefa", "#da70d6", "#da70d6", "#da70d6", "#32cd32"]
```